# does ffplay uses any option for interlaced videos?

Tags: ffmpeg

Just wondering whether ffplay needs any command-line option for interlace video for deinterlacing. I see that my output has interlacing problems.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-deinterlace` flag does what it says.  Here's the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html).

The problem is that deinterlacing isn't perfect.  It can introduce artifacts into your video -- to some degree, this is unavoidable.  You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinterlacing).

**EDIT**

Sorry, the above applies to `ffmpeg`, sister of `ffplay`.  The deinterlacing option for `ffplay` is [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#SEC81).  You can also specify the type of deinterlacing to use.

Alternatively, you can run your video through `ffmpeg` to deinterlace before playing it.

**EDIT 2**

yadif is a filter which you can include in a filter chain when playing:

```
ffplay filename -vf yadif
```

Unfortunately, there is a [bug with the current ffmpeg version](https://roundup.ffmpeg.org/issue2377) that prevents filters from being used.  The bug has been resolved, but there haven't been any new releases since then.  So, if you really want deinterlacing in ffmpeg:

1. [Download the source](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).  You may also have to satisfy some dependencies.  This step depends on your distribution.  Here's an [example](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095) for ubuntu 10.10.
2. Enable yadif when configuring: `./configure --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-filter=yadif`.  Make sure yadif comes up in the list of configured filters in the output.
3. `make`
4. Check that the yadif filter has been correctly compiled in: `./ffplay -filters | grep yadif`
5. Optionally, install the package: `make install` or `checkinstall ...`

You can then use the yadif filter as explained above.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This sounds good. But I am still confused, what option I need to use with the ffplay. Is it yadif on commandline? Sorry, but I don't have much knowledge about ffmpeg.

Comment: See my updated answer.  Actually, it's a bit harder than I thought.  But it works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Iam yet to tryout the solution.

Comment: Hi misha, thanks for the answer. do you have any answer for [this question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034905/how-important-is-a-filter-in-ffplay)