# How important is a filter in ffplay

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg

Just wanted to know whether the filters used in ffplay are really important or can I just disable the CONFIG_AV_FILTER and use it?

Also wanted to know the significance of the CONFIG_AV_FILTER.

Comment: Are you sure it's `CONFIG_AV_FILTER`?  There's no such string anywhere in the source (using `grep -R`) and Google returns no hits for it.

Comment: Oh, it's my mistake, It is CONFIG_AVFILTER. What is it and it's significance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are only significant if you plan on using them.  Have a look at what the [filters do](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html#SEC53) and then decide for yourself.

If all you do is just watch videos with `ffplay` then it's likely you won't need them.  If you use `ffmpeg` for things like analog to digital conversion, re-encoding of videos then it's likely you will need them.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, can you also tell me what is CONFIG_AVFILTER, which is widely used in ffplay.

Comment: CONFIG_AVFILTER is a constant (set by the pre-compiler `#define` directive) that specifies whether filters are available or not.  It's set by the `configure` script.  It's OK to read this value, but you shouldn't change it directly.  Use `./configure  --disable-avfilter` instead.